# Objective C: PackageApplication Failed during validation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I keep getting this error when I try to validate my app. I tried rebuilding my app from scratch with a new app ID, but it gets the same error:

```
PackageApplication failed with exit code 1.
Packaging application: '/Users/chrismanahan/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2011-08-23/My Math Buddy 8-23-11 4.44 PM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/My Math Buddy.app'
Arguments: embed=/Users/chrismanahan/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/164BE18A-21B0-4A3C-84D8-645BD21DC55A.mobileprovision  verbose=1  output=/var/folders/my/8v4j5vrn6v95rqddqcx72f6r0000gn/T/DB837C78-4E32-4A2F-9BB8-C99BAD3FF454-25681-0000721D5C5161F1/app.ipa  sign=iPhone Distribution: Christopher Manahan  
Environment variables:
HOME = /Users/chrismanahan
LOGNAME = chrismanahan
__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING = 0x1F5:0:0
DISPLAY = /tmp/launch-AhNEYx/org.x:0
COMMAND_MODE = unix2003
VERSIONER_PERL_PREFER_32_BIT = no
PATH = /Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
SHELL = /bin/bash
SSH_AUTH_SOCK = /tmp/launch-tQ0XJL/Listeners
Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render = /tmp/launch-Eb3M4j/Render
TMPDIR = /var/folders/my/8v4j5vrn6v95rqddqcx72f6r0000gn/T/
USER = chrismanahan
VERSIONER_PERL_VERSION = 5.12

Output directory: '/var/folders/my/8v4j5vrn6v95rqddqcx72f6r0000gn/T/DB837C78-4E32-4A2F-9BB8-C99BAD3FF454-25681-0000721D5C5161F1/app.ipa'
Temporary Directory: '/var/folders/my/8v4j5vrn6v95rqddqcx72f6r0000gn/T/dZUc0Z66Dl'  (will NOT be deleted on exit when verbose set)
+ /bin/cp -Rp /Users/chrismanahan/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2011-08-23/My Math Buddy 8-23-11 4.44 PM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/My Math Buddy.app /var/folders/my/8v4j5vrn6v95rqddqcx72f6r0000gn/T/dZUc0Z66Dl/Payload
Program /bin/cp returned 0 : []
### Checking original app
+ /usr/bin/codesign --verify -vvvv /Users/chrismanahan/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2011-08-23/My Math Buddy 8-23-11 4.44 PM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/My Math Buddy.app
Program /usr/bin/codesign returned 0 : [/Users/chrismanahan/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2011-08-23/My Math Buddy 8-23-11 4.44 PM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/My Math Buddy.app: valid on disk
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours and hours of slaving over this, I finally got it to work.

Solution:

I had to edit the Archive scheme to use the Distribution profile instead of the Release profile.

Answer (score 0):

You should care about this too : [apple doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/DistApps/DistApps.html)

The skip install flag made me crazy